# Space Cleaners!

Tags: code-golf

A space cleaner is a special character which removes all spaces between it and the first non space character to its left and it is represented by a '!' character.
If it reaches the beginning of the string it stops.

Given a string output the string in any reasonable format after the cleaning process.

Trailing spaces at the end of the string must be still be in the output.

Remember that space cleaners remain after their job.

Input will only consist of printable ASCII characters.

This is code-golf, so least number of bytes win.

## Test Cases

```
" ! a! !b c!d !" => "! a!!b c!d!"
"a    !" => "a!"
"!    a" => "!    a"
"!    !    !" => "!!!"
"! " => "! "
```

Comment: Some test cases would be good. I assume that the cleaners are represented by `!`s, since it isn't quite clear. So basically, this boils down to "remove any spaces before a space cleaner", correct?

Comment: Can we get some examples? What is the minimum string length? What do we do with the input string `!`? This looks like it would be trivially solved by a regex looking for any number of spaces followed by a bang?

Comment: Need some test cases,  " ! a!  !b c!d   !"=>"! a!!b c!d!"

Comment: May we choose which character to use as the "pipe cleaner"?

Comment: If the input ends with spaces can we omit them in the output?

Comment: Suggested test case `"!      "` => `"!      "`

Comment: @JoKing Yes, you are right.

Comment: @streetster Minimum string length is 0. For `!`, because the cleaner reaches the beginning of the string, it stops, and the process terminates, and `!` was outputted.

Comment: @Shaggy Space-cleaner must be `!`, as stated in the question.

Comment: @AZTECCO Test case added. For the question, nope.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle I think you've made a copy-paste error here: `"a    !" => "!    a"`. ;) Also, you might want to add a test case containing tabs instead of spaces (or a mixture of both).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Mmmm, yep. EDIT: Fixed.

Comment: You should probably describe what "eats a space" means in the context of this puzzle.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Edited.

Comment: @JoKing Tabs can appear, according to Kevin Cruijssen's test case.

Comment: @JoKing Since I'm pretty much new to Code Golf Stack Exchange, I really don't know what to do - e. g. shall the input restriction be language dependent.

Comment: @JoKing Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
„ !¤:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8BcVDS6z@/1dUgEAgSFRIAjGSAQ)

---

#### Explanation

```
„ !                  # 2 char string " !"
   ¤                 # Push the tail of that (so "!") 
    :                # Infinite replacement
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 5 bytes

```
 +!
!
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9BW5FL8f9/RYVERQXFJIVkxRQFRa5EBSAAioOoRAilCBXiBGIA)

Not much to say. Simply removes all spaces in front of every `!` with a simple replace.

Comment: 4th test case `!    !    !` -> `!!!` why not `!    !!` ?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Why not? I assume all space cleaners 'walk' simultaneously, so eventually they'll reach the start of the string for that test case. OP never stated the left one walks first, only that all space cleaners travel left.

Comment: maybe the OP should clarify

Comment: The assumption is correct. (Which, if I'm not mistaken, is equivalent to "the left ones first".)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

<sup>Thanks to @Nick Kennedy for the TIO link and -2 bytes, since I could omit the function name `f=`</sup>

```js
_=>_.replace(/ +!/g,'!')
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr7QsQFRYXfArBCsQDREChu/XuyfMMKjf7dvmzsmxd4c3PbYSKCoLC9q8SpSaqb6jlmhKzSopAQgBAU8gvACF1vwD)

Nothing special, same regex as other answers. New to `codegolf`, was a simple one to translate to js. If anyone can think of improvements I'd love to see them.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I like the underline obfuscation LOL.

Comment: Welcome! Would suggest having a [Try it online](https://tio.run) link with a working example. Also you can move the naming of the lambda to a header and remove it from the byte count. e.g. https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAr7QsQFRYXfArBCsQDREChu/XuyfMMKjf7dvmzsmxd4c3PbYSKCoLC9q8SpSaqb6jlmhKzSopAQgBAU8gvACF1vwD

Comment: @NickKennedy Thanks! I wasn't sure about the function naming, good to know. I considered the TIO link but figured it's easy enough to test JS with browser console. Although, I will edit it into my post.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace('/ +!/','!',$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1Pb4otSAnMTlVQ11fQVtRX11HXVFdRyWxKD1P0/p/anJGvoJSTJ6S9X8FRYVERQXFJIVkxRQFRa5EBSBQ5FIEUYkQShEm9C@/oCQzP6/4v64bAA)

Just a simple RegEx replace.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>48</s> 42 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to H.PWiz!*

```hs
g(' ':b)|'!':_<-g b=g b
g(a:b)=a:g b
g a=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYjBDkAwEAXvvuKtSMqhP9Dot8i2WKKkwdG3W43DJDOz8LVNKalKa2Bc6B5Dxg29FQRfqKTlcj27P8Cedef1gEc@1@NGA0ENAhMoINJYvNY3zonlUhtz/gA)

#### Explanation:

```hs
g(' ':b)                 -- Given a string starting with space
        |'!':_           -- Check if '!' is the first element of
              <-g b      -- The function applied to the rest of it
                   =g b  -- Return the function applied to the rest of it
g(a:b)=a:g b             -- Otherwise just apply the function recursively
g a=a                    -- Until the string is empty
```

Comment: You don't need parens around `g b`. Also, you can replace `g b!!0=='!'` with `'!':_<-g b`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
gsub(" +!","!",scan(,''))
```

Straightforward enough with a simple regex substitution!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P724NElDSUFbUUlHCYiLkxPzNHTU1TU1/yspKCokKiooJikkK6YoKCr9BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:' !'in s and f(s.replace(' !','!'))or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYs7DoAgEERrPcVsBSbGxs7Ew6wCkUSRgI2nR2hM/Ew3783481h216dkxpW3STHiIEDCOkSwUzAydkH7lWcti2gFiabZA2LywbpDmoLBBJowk0LR9a0YOU9EBfEX0c@0evXvKyfDdAE)

Port of [Expired Data's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191568/87681), so make sure to upvote him!

---

Original answer:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s:'!'.join(i.rstrip(' ')for i in(s+'_').split('!'))[:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvBCsIwEETP@hW7p02QBsRbwS@xUraW4EpNQpKLXx@3F0Hr3ObNm/Sq9xhOzZ@HtvBzmhlKT0juESUYcbnULMkQkPUxg4DScqCRrCtpkWrUtfbSd8drS1lCNV5lBEbACW44w7rvPxOD5hvhiniL8I@6@@nbl0ZhewM)

Comment: [Isn't just using regex easier and shorter?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqihVr7g0SUNJQVtRSUcJiIs1uTJzC/KLShSKUv8XFGXmlWikaagrKCokKiooJikkK6YoKKpranLBpRIVgABVSBEklIgppIhFKScaH8j7DwA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, for sure! I just like to try without.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 66 bytes

```
,[<<++++[->++++++++<]>>[-<-<+>>]<[+[[+]<<[.<]>[>]]<.>>]>>,]<<<[.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBCoAwDATAryTntH3Bsh8JObQVQQQPgu@vQZzjjLsf1/7Mc63igCWvtB@C9IoKIwNu7haAt3xnBFo2WfK@XEtUuooOmbqJvg)

It's funny how much space is just taken up by constants, in this case making a space takes up more than a quarter of the code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
foldr(%)""
' '%r@('!':_)=r
c%s=c:s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdBCoAgFEXReat4SqIN2oAgtJAg7JcVWYm2/n7RnRzu6ss@x8jB9RyuOGWjGikrDa1yZ7TQdmhcrkgVR7bw4bcTDilv540aARJfAl78jiAxfSv5oRD9UrillF4)

Answer (score 3):

## [ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/), 18 bytes

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P8/NTkjX0Gl2lBfX1tDQVNRX7H2////CooKiYoKikkKyYopCooA)

```perl
echo ${1//+( )!/!}
```

**zsh, 32 bytes**

<sub>Since there's another **zsh** answer I changed to **ksh**. Thanks to @Gilles at [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541616/62529) for zsh help. [try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9vzi1JL@gRCG7OCM@PSc/icvGxkal2lBfX1tDQVNRX7H2fy1XmoJ6VUpxmgIYKIKwOkgMwktUVFBMUkhWTIGKJirAFYCUKiQimIrIUur/AQ)</sub> 

`setopt ksh_glob;<<<${1//+( )!/!}`

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 6 bytes

```
/ !/!/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xDsIwDET3fMU5lZiQuiPBwE8wmzSohTSp6lSIrw9J00rg6fzufBbH0ltJqQW11KYGNwvDHs9FIrqA4C2izdqw2CPc8Mp7P8hJKRCYQHcY6kAqT4PrEvGuDewk1BoTpg8OmFhiObZj9twR7DuIXQnizF4eYR45DsGj52myPnfq/yca5wt0QZWQVpqRZ3O4ACqA9@iqN0g/UaKa3XNapS8)

Replaces every occurrence of  `!` with `!` until it eats up all the spaces in front of the exclamation marks.

The language is a perfect match because it's built on find/replace. That's the only command you're given, and not a single special character or wild card to use in your patterns, except the `\` which only serves to escape the `/`. Yet, it's Turing complete. It's really elegant!

The language is read by slash triplets, hence the name. Each one couches a find pattern and replace pattern. We have one such pattern here doing precisely what it says at the top. The first pair of slashes says to find all  `!` and the second pair says to replace them with `!`.

Comment: What I intended. But input: `/` :(

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 (`-p`), 9 bytes

```
s/ *!/!/g
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0FLUV9RP/3/f0WFREUFxSSFZMUUBUWuRAUgUORSBFGJEEoRKsQJxP/yC0oy8/OK/@sWAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 38 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub(' +!','!',s)
import re
```

A simple regex substitution. Replaces any amount of space plus an exclamation mark with just an exclamation mark.

Comment: Why using a raw string? `lambda s:re.sub(' *!','!',s)` is a byte shorter.

Comment: @Skillmon Man, that habit is hard to break for code golf. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 22 bytes

```powershell
$args-replace' +!','!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9WLcotSAnMTlVXUFbUV1HXVH9fy0Xl5pKmoKSB1BhvqKCoqICFCgqJCr9BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
œṣ⁾ !j”!µÐL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fz9q3KegmPWoYa7ioa2HJ/j81zncDhRSUsp6tHEdUHiOgq6dAlCWCyjctCby/38lBUWFREUFxSSFZMUUBUUlHaVEBSAAMRRBjEQYQxEhrAQA)

Answer (score 2):

#### Zsh with `extended_glob`, 14 bytes

```
<<<${1// #!/!}
```

Zsh with `extended_glob` is not an arbitrary whim: it's the language in which zsh completion functions are written. Inspired by [roblogic's initial attempt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541616). [Try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWpJfUKKQWlGSmpeSmhKfnpOf9N/Gxkal2lBfX0FZUV@x9v///woKigqKigoA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
≔ ηＦ⮌Ｓ«≡ι!≔ωη ≔ηι≔ η←ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1LDsIgAETXcIqBFST1AnXl0sSF0RMghUJCqAHaLkzPjp82dTnzJm@0U0kPKtR6ytn3UXDwBk4eqR0SxM1MJmUjzvE5lntJPvZCSrwoybMv2kH4X9IqG3DGW2yaeZVsAH/gGvgv6IxVYyh7v/@ShZLr56iI9mJsWedLrWBQDOwBzTowWg9TeAM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ η
```

`h` is a variable that specifies whether a space is being cleaned or not.

```
Ｆ⮌Ｓ«
```

Loop over the string in reverse as the spaces are cleaned to the left.

```
≡ι
```

Switch over the current character.

```
!≔ωη
```

If it's a `!` then start cleaning spaces.

```
 ≔ηι
```

If it's a space then replace it with the space cleaning flag.

```
≔ η
```

Otherwise turn off space cleaning.

```
←ι
```

Print the current character leftwards.

Boring 15-byte version:

```
Ｗ№θ !≔⪫⪪θ !¦!θθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDOb80r0SjUEdBSUFRSVNTwbG4ODM9T8MrPzNPI7ggJxMhB6TAZKGmNVdAUSZIl6b1//8KigqJigqKSQrJiikKilz/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ№θ !
```

Repeat while there are spaces to be cleaned.

```
≔⪫⪪θ !¦!θ
```

Clean up to one space per space cleaner.

```
θ
```

Output the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Recursive replacement. Could save 2 bytes if we could choose the "cleaner" character.

```
e" !"'!
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZSIgISInIQ&input=ImEgYiAgICAgISAgISAgYyI)

Comment: I didn't get how did you save bytes by changing the cleaner character.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle, Japt has constants for a few characters & digits (e.g., `T===0`), which would allow me to do something like `eS+TT` (where `S` is Japt's constant for a single space).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I choose ! just because it's next to the space in the ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 79 bytes

```c
j,e;f(char*s){for(j=e=0;!e;e=!*s++)*s-32?s-=*s-33?j:0,j=0,*s&&putchar(*s):j++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LbsIwEEX38xUzXiA7DxES2GAZPgSxcFOHxioBxWaV5tvTOFCFZlYz596jKdPyWzeXofzSLfrN6aw6hoSakD6wpE8k1ktYr1EdkAX@xMQQnko@KXrqvWp6TouQTuIch@MVbyd5/PWuE83@7s9/1xkADDYxsuKhFTnRVbeWW2VUJslIoyhycSwilxb50aUqLMXR7rPEqiyJ3Gp1f/ig8tHd2ziW/VA3Hq@6brjADiruN0KOJcfZDxMygHwJiiXYLsHuHwDAcVrjH22DmYR@@AU)

Saved 1 thanks to @ceilingcat 
*s && instead of !*s ||

j is used to jump back if there is no "!" after spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/\s+\!/!/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxDoJAEIThnqeY2cJCErazMEEfwvaaBTljAkK4ihB99ZMTSNxq880/NGN7it2Eg0cZ59v5oS7kjkp9x2ATPD6dOimOVycK349on68mRAFhBCvUvIOC8gJJtAolE8Ny22IJmMD29PdvyL@UXNu9ky8)

Loses bytes over other regex solutions since I can't use a literal space and I have to escape the metaoperator `!`

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
(#~1-' !'E.])^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NZTrDHXVFRTVXfViNeOs4v9rcqUmZ@QrqCsqJCoqJikkK6YoqivoWimkATWDxBQggkAdUIWJcPlEBSCAiyuCeIkwOSgPJqeoiCKhiKYTIan@HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 14 bytes

```ruby
gsub(/ +!/,?!)
```

Unfortunately the 13-byte `gsub / +!/,?!` doesn't work because Ruby interprets the first `/` as division instead of the start of a regex statement.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P724NElDX0FbUV/HXlHz/38FRYVERQXFJIVkxRQFRa5EBSBQ5FIEUYkQShEu9C@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8+, 26 bytes

Yet another regex port

```java
s->s.replaceAll(" +!","!")
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##XU67jsIwEOz9FWNXsTjyAReBRENHRXmiWBIbGUwSeRckFOXbc0agSLDF7Mzu7ONMd1qem8tUR2LGjkI7qNCKS55qh@2wlxTaE3zxJmyrUfW3Yww1WEhyunehwTVPvj1/B1A6sR3UFh6riZdrLpPrY964ibEwWGjzY7SxU6XmEXEsjBUGhRwGGqShj6h1g2x/VemJs9JPpA@lvwyZjZXyXZr/x@/rlMX@weKuZXeTss89iW3hS1@wtZUax@kf)

Comment: I think lambdas where first introduced in Java 8.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I had a brain short-circuit there

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
aRw.'!'!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MahcT11RXfH///8KigqJigqKSQrJiikKigA)

concatenates the whitespace regex variable `w` with an `!` character. then replaces it with a single `!` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ωσ" !""!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18erPOoqfH/@c7zzUoKikpKiv///48GshQSFRUUkxSSFVOAojpKiQpAAGIoghiJMIYiQlgpFgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 16 bytes

```
gsub(" *!","!")1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0SUNJQUtRSUdJUUnT8P//RIUkhTQA)

Similar regex to some others that were posted, just AWK-styled.  Adding a random number on the end makes sure it prints even if the input has no cleaner character.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
` *!`\!øṙ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%20*!%60%5C!%C3%B8%E1%B9%99&inputs=%20%20%20!%20!%20a%20%20!&header=&footer=)

Another one ports the regex